# Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "fi") when using calculations

Tags: test, syntax

I am relatively new to shell, and I am getting a syntax error where I am still confused.

```
#!/bin/dash

ls="ls -l test"
small=0
medium=0
large=0

for i in $(seq 11 9 56)
do
    filename=$(echo $($ls) | cut -d ' ' -f $i)
    count=$(wc -w test/$filename | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
    if [ "$count" -lt 10 ]; then
        small=(( $small+1 ))
    elif [ "$count" -gt 100 ]; then
        large=(( $large+1 ))
    else
        medium=(( $medium+1 ))
    fi
done
echo $small
echo $medium
echo $large
```

In this code, I am trying to get a list of files, retrieve how many words a file has, and sort them into small/medium/large size files.
I am pretty sure I haven't made any syntax errors for incrementing the variables using `test`, but they don't seem to work within an if statement. Can anyone help me out with this? There is a syntax error when using multiple brackets within an if statement, but I have no idea what it is.

Comment: I don't know dash very well, but `small=(( $small+1 ))` should probably be `small=$(( $small+1 ))`.  I.e., you want the variable `small` to be assigned the *value* that comes from the arithmetic operation `$small + 1`.  The lines with assignments to `medium` and `large` would benefit from the same syntax change.

Comment: The shell tells you on which line the error occurs. Did you think it was a good idea not to tell us?

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: If you redirect the file like `wc -w < test/$filename`, it will not print the filename, so you won't need to cut it off. Also, inside `$(( ... ))` words are assumed to be variables: `small=$(( small + 1 ))` is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
large=$(( $large + 1 ))
```

Or even better:

```
large=$(( large + 1 ))
```

Not <strike>`large=(( $large+1 ))`</strike>.

Korn-like shells also have `(( large = large + 1 ))` or `(( large += 1 ))` or `(( large++ ))` but even though POSIX specified ksh's the `$((...))` *arithmetic expansion* operator for `sh`, they left out the `((...))` *arithmetic expression* operator, so `dash` didn't bother implement it.

In any case, the rest of your script doesn't make much sense either. You probably meant something like:

```
#! /bin/sh -

small=0 medium=0 large=0
for file in test/*; do
  words=$(wc -w < "$file") || continue
  if [ "$words" -lt 10 ]; then    # 0 to 9
    small=$(( small + 1 ))
  elif [ "$words" -gt 100 ]; then # 101 and above
    large=$(( large + 1 ))
  else                            # 10 to 100
    medium=$(( medium + 1))
  fi
done

printf '%s\n' "$small" "$medium" "$large"
```

You could also do something like:

```
...
  if [ "$words" -lt 10 ]; then    # 0 to 9
    kind=small
  elif [ "$words" -gt 100 ]; then # 101 and above
    kind=large
  else                            # 10 to 100
    kind=medium
  fi
  : "$(( $kind += 1 ))"
...
```

Where the arithmetic expansion has the side effect of incrementing the value of the variable whose name is stored in `$kind`, and we discard the result of that expansion by passing it to the `:` null-command, so in effect it's similar to the ksh-style `(( $kind += 1 ))`.

Answer (score 0):

You need `var=$(( expr ))` instead of `var=(( expr ))`

`(` is a control operator for `dash` i.e. it separates words. So `var=(...` cannot make sense because it becomes `var= (...`

`((` is known to (e.g.) `bash` but not to `dash` so it's not surprising that this does not work.

It does not work in `bash` either as `bash` allows variable assignments in simple commands only but in front of a compound command (like `(( ))`).